# Strptime How to convert to a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, strptime

*Hello i'm trying to obtain an datetime object with "T" and "Z" so i can pass it to youtube API. After i convert it the STRPTIME can't match the format and i don't understand why, i have tried all day to get rid of this.*

```
actual_time = datetime.utcnow()
    actual_time = actual_time.isoformat("T") +"Z"
    actual_time = datetime.strptime(actual_time, '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
    print(actual_time)
```

This is the error i get:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %

time data '2022-09-03T09:52:49.464164Z' does not match format '%y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 3, 10, 7, 8, 681996, tzinfo=tzutc())` is this form acceptable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)

Comment: Btw. it's `%Y` for parsing 4-digit year, not %y

Answer (score 1):

from dateutil library import parser then convert into `parser.parser()`

**Code:**

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime
actual_time = datetime.utcnow()
actual_time = actual_time.isoformat("T") +"Z"
print("actual time",actual_time)
parser.parse(actual_time)
```

**Output:**

```
actual time 2022-09-03T10:09:36.784768Z
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 3, 10, 9, 36, 784768, tzinfo=tzutc())
```